# New line character lost in transfer from linux to windows

Tags: java, windows, linux, character-encoding, nio

I wrote a simple client/server in java that transfers files using java NIO Socketchannel. When I transfer a simple text file from Linux to Windows, the line returns are all gone. I know the two operating systems use different character encodings, but I'm trying to figure out where in the process I would take that into account.

When the server sends the files, it just sends the raw bytes over, read in by a `FileInputStream`.

My client reads in the bytes from the channel to a ByteBuffer, then I get the byte array out of that.

```
socketChannel.read(this.readBuffer);
```

I loop through the array of bytes each time I receive more from the channel, looking for EOF, and if I don't find it, I put it into a file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
fos.write(data);  //data is my byte[]
fos.close();
```

I know this probably has an obvious solution to some, but I'm not too familiar with all the concepts involved.

Comment: Any reason you're using the FileInputStream in lieu of FileReader? From the doc for FileInputStream: FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

Comment: I asked because FileReader will respect/preserve newlines for you. (though it's been 8+ months since I used java.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic problem is that Linux has \n as newline and windows comprised of  \r (carriage return)and \n (line feed).

To get the system's line separator by:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Now the question where you gonna put it. Now if you want to save the file at the client side with client side line separator then use the above api to the get the line separator and replace in the data.

Since you have no idea on the client side what server is using (i m trying to go for generic soln) for line separate, try to replace both type of line separators with the client side line separators.

Answer (score 1):

In Unix the newline is the character `\n`, while in Windows it is the pair `\r\n`. So you can consider looking through the buffer each time and inserting a `\r` in front of `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

This writes line by line to the file:

```
byte[] buff = "line1\nline2\nline3".getBytes();   
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buff);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
File file = new File("C:\\folder", "outputFile.txt");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    ps.println(line);
}
br.close();
ps.close();
```

Finally, the content of `outputFile.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: I like this solution if I were sending only a few packets of information.  But I'll be sending over byte arrays in packets of about 4kb for files that may reach up to 300MB.  The overhead of instantiating these objects thousands of times would be a bit much I think.  Though I do like the idea. Thanks!